# Script to identify email account type

Tags: javascript, email, exchange-server, imap, pop3

I need help / direction to write a script that will find the type of a mailbox by it's address. (such as: POP, IMAP or Exchange)
For example I'll type: 'xxx@gmail.com' and the response will be 'pop/imap'.

I believe it is possible because I know blackberry systems for example can do it when you configure email accounts, or even smart phones can..

I tought trying to communicate with the server by known ports like 110 and so using telnet, but it won't work because exchange is able to use any port.

I prefer using javascript for this job.

Thanks,
Rotem

Comment: But a mailbox can be accessed via both POP and IMAP... its not necessarily one or the other.

Comment: you want to telnet with javascript ? weird. you should better create a JSONP service that scans server side and send you the result back. You could nmap some commons ports to discover services and banners.

Comment: "I prefer using javascript for this job" - sorry but if you don't know any of the many things wrong with that statement you're going to have trouble implementing any sort of solution.

Comment: I don't see any problem usint telnet with javascript, it is possible and I did it before. If any of you can help me find a solution I'll appreciate it, but don't write false comments please.. @matthewh I know that some of the mailboxes are accessed in both ways, but not all of them, in this case I want to return both of the available protocols. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to implement the [Exchange Autodiscover](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc433481%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) protocol, this is designed for ActiveSync clients to automatically detect settings based on an email address. However, this requires further setup on the Exchange server and not all systems will support this.

Another option would be to do an MX lookup on the domain, connect to SMTP port, and make some assumptions based on what the server claims to be (`Microsoft ESMTP MAIL` is what Windows will answer with, but that doesn't necessarily indicate an Exchange server).

BlackBerry devices do not support Exchange ActiveSync without third party software or server-side BES. Windows Mobile devices will use the Autodiscover protocol for Exchange servers, or ask the user to enter Exchange details manually it the server does not support it.

Comment: Hi, I found a little bit info about mx lookup earlier, what is the exact code for finding the mailbox type? This is like 'nslookup', right? Blackberry doesn't support Exchange as you said, but if the BIS administration system discover that this is exchange server it tries to configure it as OWA. For my purpose I can assume that if the email isn't POP or IMAP it is exchange. I just need a script that will recieve email address or just the domain and returns 'pop/imap' or 'exchange'. Thank you very much..